# How to integrate reactive features of Spring Webflux into 'standard' Spring MVC Application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

During my project development, I found myself to the point where I realised that I need some event driven functions as some of them may be time-consuming and it would be much better to not block IO then (images processing, emails etc).

So far I have 'standard' MVC application, which is mainly REST API.

How can I integrate event driven stuff? Do I have to rebuild all controllers to fulfil Webflux architecture or it is possible to have an `EventBus` (but I found that it is now deprecated?) so I could just emit some events(e.g. imageUploaded) where I need it and consume them in Consumers (e.g. create thumbnail when imageUploaded?

I cannot find any clear information or complete guide as few of nice tutorials refer to classes which have been deprecated recently.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Depending on your constraints, you don't necessarily need WebFlux to achieve that. Using `DeferredResult` and application events (with work dispatched on an Executor) would work. My point is, this question is too vague to come up with a good answer.